# Traduko de "manual" (malo de aŭtomata)

Tags: translation

Kelkaj programoj havas du eblojn por ĝisdatigoj: *automatic updates* aŭ *manual updates*.

Por *manual* oni trovas kiel tradukojn: *mana*, *permana* sed tiujn eblojn mi sentas kiel rektajn pruntojn en tiu kunteksto (cetere en PIV tiu signifo por *man/* ne aperas).

Mi emas uzi *neaŭtomata* aŭ *malaŭtomata* sed mi sentas ke oni devus povi esprimi alimaniere ke io okazos **nur** pro homa volo, indiko, interago, ...

Ĉu iu havas alian proponon?

Comment: Elektu, ĉu vi volas ĝisdatigi aŭtomate aŭ laŭdeziro.

Comment: Kial vi opinias _permana_ maltaŭga? Ĉu oni ne devas per la mano ion fari (alklaki butonon per muso ekz.) por instali la ĝisdatigon?

Comment: @Joffysloffy *permana* estas por mi tro fakta, limiga. Uzi *permane* pro musalklako sur butonoj *Jes/Ne* senteblas kiel uzi *permane* por arbohakado. La aga ilo estas butono/hakilo. Jes, mano kutime partoprenas, sed ne tiel rekte por la butonoj (kiujn oni povus peli ankaŭ per parolo, ekzemple). Laŭ mi, ĉi okaze ĝusta traduko rilatus pli deziron/interagon ol manon. Notu ke mi ne opinias *permana* malĝusta, mi nur sentas ĝin kiel lingvan prunton. Tamen *man/* estas uzata kiel parto de tiu traduko en pluraj lingvoj, do eble *"semantika interpreto"* de la dekkvina regulo pravigus *permane*.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Vi pravas kaj mi konsentas, ke tia uzo estas iom malpreciza. Tamen la uzo de la radiko _man_ en diversaj kunmetaĵoj estas ja iom aparta: _manskribita_ teksto estas teksto skribita per ekzemple plumo, tenata en la mano, _manlaboro_ ne nepre estas sen iloj, sed per iloj rekte uzataj per la manoj, ktp. Sed verŝajne tia uzo de _man_ estas iel pruntita de aliaj lingvoj, ĉar tio ne vere estas en la radika signifo.

Comment: Konsciu, ke ankaŭ [la angla adjektivo "manual" (el la latina "manualis") origine signifis "mana" aŭ "permana"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manual) en laŭlitera per-mano(j)-aŭ-pere-de-mano(j)-a senco.

Comment: Ankaŭ [Komputeko (prikomputila terminokolekto) trakukas la adjektivon "manual"](https://komputeko.net/#manual) al "mana"  aŭ "permana". Eĉ "permana kaŝmemorigo", kio vere ne eblas laŭlitere per la manoj, ĉu?

Comment: Kvankam `permana` ŝajnas plej komprenebla de legantoj, `(hom)stirita/homdirektita` ankaŭ eblus.

Answer (score 1):

Ni pensu pri la situacio kaj kiajn alternativojn oni tiam havas. *Automatic update* signifas, ke la sistemo ĝisdatigas sin mem, sen interveno de uzanto. *Manual update* signifas, ke la ĝisdatigo ne okazas aŭtomate, ke la uzanto devas fari ion, ekz. preni butonon.

Oni povas rigardi la lastan alternativon el diversaj perspektivoj. Se oni koncentriĝas en agon, prenadon de butono, certe oni povas prezenti la alternativon per:

- mana/permana ĝisdatigo

Teorie oni povus diri:

- perfingra ĝisdatigo

sed miaopinie tio estas tro litera.

Se oni volas emfazi, ke ne temas pri aŭtomata ĝisdatigo:

- neaŭtomata/malaŭtomata ĝisdatigo

Se oni volas emfazi, ke la ĝisdatigo okazas nur laŭ deziro aŭ elekto de uzanto:

- laŭdezira/laŭelekta ĝisdatigo

Persone mi preferas tian alternativon, kiu emfazas, ke la uzanto elektas, kion ĝisdatigi. Do eble

`Elektu, kiel vi volas ricevi ĝisdatigojn:`

⚪︎ `aŭtomate`

⚫︎  `laŭ elekto/laŭelekte/mi elektos`